# xinetd cannot launch lighttpd

Tags: xinetd, lighttpd

I want to launch `lighttpd` when someone tries to connect to port 80.
I started with a simple test script to see if anything was working:

`/etc/xinetd.d/www`

```
service www
{
    disable         = no
    socket_type     = stream
    protocol        = tcp
    port              = 80
    log_on_success += USERID 
    log_on_failure += USERID
    server          = /usr/server_test.sh
    user            = root
    instances       = UNLIMITED
    wait            = no
    log_type        = SYSLOG daemon debug
}
```

where `/usr/server_test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "www connection"
lighttpd -D -f /usr/lighttpd.conf &
webconfig -c /usr/cppcms.js &

service xinetd restart
```

When I try:

```
nc localhost 80
```

I get:

```
www connection 2013-11-25 16:37:13: (network.c.345) can't bind to port:  80 Address already in use
```

How do I get `xinetd` and `lighttpd` to work together, not fight over same port?

Comment: lighttpd is not meant to work that way, you should just run it as a daemon. This bug was closed as wontfix by the developer team: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/1584

Comment: Ahh, nice spotted. But is there any way to do this, then without xinetd ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not do it this way, run `lighttpd` strictly as a daemon. The daemon `xinetd` is mean to start services that are not actually running all the time. When `xinetd` sees traffic it "spins up" a particular service to meet the need, but otherwise the processes are not running.

By the way, you cannot share a TCP port between 2 daemons/services. Only one service can bind to a particular TCP port, essentially owning it for the duration of the time that it's running.

#### Doing it anyway

If you're absolutely sure you want to run it like this then take a look at this tutorial that shows exactly this scenario on a Raspberry Pi. The tutorial is titled: [Starting mysqld and httpd on demand with xinetd](http://www.sanxiago.com/linux/starting-mysqld-and-httpd-on-demand-with-xinetd/).

This script was created, `/etc/xinetd.init.d/lighttpd`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# inspired on this article
# https://www.linuxnet.ch/automatic-tunnels-with-xinetd-and-netcat/
# script is called from xinetd
# script starts and stops service using /etc/init.d scripts

SERVICE=/etc/init.d/lighttpd  # script used to start/stop service
PORT=81 # port where end service should listen
PID_FILE=/var/run/lighttpd.pid # pid file generated by init script
REAPER_PID_FILE="/var/run/lighttpd_reaper.pid" # pid file generated by this script
REAPER_SLEEP=180 # The reaper sleeps in seconds and checks for idle conns
LOG=/var/log/syslog # where to log messages

# this function checks if we already have reaper
check_reaper(){
        if  [ -s $REAPER_PID_FILE ]
        then
                reaper_pid=`cat $REAPER_PID_FILE 2>/dev/null`
                ps -p $reaper_pid &> /dev/null
                if [ $? -ne 0 ]
                then
                        start_reaper &    # If we don't have a reaper we start one
                        echo $! > $REAPER_PID_FILE
                fi
        else
                start_reaper &
                echo $! > $REAPER_PID_FILE
        fi

}

# this function starts a reaper, which is a background process that will kill the end service if its inactive
start_reaper(){
        while [ -f $PID_FILE ]
        do
                sleep $REAPER_SLEEP                                      # We wait
                touched=`stat --printf %W $REAPER_PID_FILE 2>/dev/null`  # We check when the reaper PID was last touched
                now=`date +%s 2>/dev/null`
                let idle=$now-$touched
                if [ $idle -gt $REAPER_SLEEP ]              # If reaper pid has not been touched in more than a sleep cycle we stop the service
                then
                        echo `date`" REAPER STOPPING SERVICE AFTER BEING $idle" >> $LOG   
                        $SERVICE stop >> $LOG               # This is the stop service instruction
                        rm $REAPER_PID_FILE 
                        exit 0
                fi
        done
}


# This is where we start our service
start_service(){
        sleep 1                    # Added a delay to trouble shoot as browsers kickstart several connections, we need to allow the PID file to be created this can be improved.
        if [ -s $PID_FILE ]        # We check if the PID file for the end service exist to avoid calling the start script when the service has already been started
        then
                return
        else
                echo `date`" STARTING $SERVICE" >> $LOG
                $SERVICE start &>> $LOG                  #this is the start service instruction
                return
        fi
}

# We probe and wait for the service to come on line
wait_for_service(){
        nc -w30 -z 127.0.0.1 $PORT &>/dev/null          # probe end port with a timeout of 30 seconds
        if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
        then
                echo `date`" XINET SERVICE START ON $PORT TIMED OUT" >> $LOG
        fi
}

# This is were all the magic happens netcat passes traffic back and forth
transmit(){
        nc -w30 127.0.0.1 $PORT 2>/dev/null  # netcat is awesome, timeout flag of 30 seconds can be adjusted
}

# this is the main program that is called every time
main()
{
        nc -z 127.0.0.1 $PORT &>/dev/null  # We probe the end service
        if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]                  # If its not responding
        then
                start_service              # We start service
                wait_for_service           # We wait for service to became online
        fi
        check_reaper                       # We always check we have a reaper
        touch $REAPER_PID_FILE             # We log activity by touching the reaper PID file
        transmit                           # We transmit data 
        exit 0                             
}

main
```

And the following xinetd service was created:

```
service http
{
        disable         = no
        socket_type     = stream
        protocol        = tcp
        port              = 80
        server = /etc/xinetd.init.d/lighttpd
        user            = root
        wait            = no
}
```

Comment: We have a small embedded system, so we would, if possible, only launch programs when needed.

Comment: @JakobJ - see updates.